# Connecting to Oracle DB with tunnel from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, ssh-tunnel

I have to connect to an external Oracle database. For this I use putty to create an ssh tunnel and then sqldeveloper as a client.

This is the connection from sqldeveloper and it works fine:
[image: Oracle Connection]

Now I have to consume this data from an ASP.NET application. I installed the oracle packages for entity framework but when I type "localhost" from the Server Explorer it tries to connect to a local instance of Oracle.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: wouldn't you just use VPN?  Once connected to the network, your tnsnames should resolve the db

Comment: I´m affraid that´s not a possibility